# String concatenation in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula (without the preceding `=` sign) in a cell, and I want to copy it to a diff cell and add the preceding `=` sign. I need to do this in a macro and I also have to use absolute numbers of the cells and not relative references. How do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 4):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  .Range("A1").Formula = "=" & .Range("B1").Value
End With
```